# _UIReplicantView and snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates how to get its content?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiview, screenshot

`-renderInContext:` has been used widely since its appearance, but with it is impossible to render OpenGL layer, AVPreviewLayer (probably because is a sort of OpenGL layer) and I still wasn't able to render a CATiledLayer correctly. 
With iOS7 were introduced 2 new APIs to get screenshots, one is `-snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates:` that returns a particular view (`_UIReplicantView`) and `-drawViewHierarchyInRect:afterScreenUpdates:` the last one is a sort of replacement for `-renderInContext`, unfortunately it seems to have the same limitations. 
The -snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates: it seems to work also with OpenGL and AVPreviewLayer, unfortunately a view like that is not very useful if you want to do particular animations or use the contents as background of something (such as a uibutton). I've tried to get the contents off from the returned view, but I still get no luck. 
Has somebody tried yet?

Comment: But what are you trying to do with the view that returns `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates`? you can generate a UIImage from that view and use it, but you cannot access the `contents` of the underlying layer

Comment: Have you ever tried to get a UIImage from a _UIReplicantView? At least on iOS7 returns a blank image

Comment: I'm not in front of the code, so I will check when I arrive at home.. I hav a game and I think I'm using one of those methods to get a screenshot. I don't remember exactly which one. (I am rendering an OpenGL layer in the game and the screenshot works) I will check later and post again.

Comment: @Andrea Hi, have you been able to solve it?  I ran into a similar problem where I need to capture camera preview but don't have access to the recording session.   `snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates` is the only thing that can capture camera preview.  But I couldn't save an image from it.

Comment: Nope... I just think that is not possibile. You can use use buffer delegation ti get single frames from camera instead of making snapshot

Comment: Did you folks try UIView.snapshotView or UIScreen.snapshotView? Those are two different methods: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622531-snapshotview and https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiscreen/1617814-snapshotview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have struggled with exactly this issue, initially we worked around it by hooking into the NSRunLoop and rendering to an image and then merging them together.  It was really messy.

Then we found a piece of code that would appear to solve this issue, but you have to be prepared to think outside the box a little bit.

That framework records a video of a UIWindow, we were then just stopping the record.  Shoving it through a AVAssetImageGenerator (or something like that), and grabbing the image out.

As I say it's very much a weird way to solve it, but it seems to work okay for us.

The code for (ASScreenRecorder) can be found in this library here.

https://github.com/alskipp/ASScreenRecorder

One of our menu's in our product was OpenGL and some had video backgrounds!  And this worked perfectly for us.  But I cant be sure if it was something particular to our implementation and use of OpenGL.  It definitely does work for camera views though as his example video's show.

Comment: It seems really a lot but if it works.. I will look into that

Comment: Hi were you able to get Image from UIReplicantView?? I am having the same issue. I have tried ASScreenRecorder is well but it is showing black area where video is playing, rest everything on view it shows.