# No camera view just white background when taking a screeshot

Tags: ios, swift, camera, uiimage

I have a live camera view that I want only part of it to be included inside a circular UIImage when I take a screenshot. All I get is the circular UIImage and a white background.
I call the circular image a circleImage and the camera view a camView:

```
self.camView = self.faceImage.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(false)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.circleImage.bounds.size, false, 0);
    self.circleImage.drawViewHierarchyInRect(self.camView.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true)
    var image:UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    var imageData:NSData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    //Save it to the camera roll
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately is the wanted behavior, there is no way to capture the content of a AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer using `renderInContext` or `drawViewHierarchy` the only solution seems to read the data output of the session from the buffer delegate, when you need an image you grab it from here.
For more info check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19567007/uireplicantview-and-snapshotviewafterscreenupdates-how-to-get-its-content), there is also a good alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you Andrea! I'll look into that and hopefully it works for me.